# A meteor tutorial puzzle, is the client authorization safe?

Tags: meteor

I went through this tutorial and I'm trying to figure out how authorization works:

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-15-meteor-building-a-web-app-from-scratch-in-meteor

I see that client-side code is well written and that it handles privileges for logged in users through calls to

```
if(Meteor.userId())
```

but as far as I can tell nothing is handling client authorization in the server-side code in `epollserver.js`.

I tried to create a script that likes questions in a for loop but failed :) So I'm wondering if I'm missing something about the blog, something about the way metamagics work in meteor or if the tutorial actually results with unsafe code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the tutorial does result with unsafe code since I managed to add a question through the JS console without being logged in, my initial hunch that the code lacks server-side checks was correct

I suspect three more `if(Meteor.userId())` in `epollserver.js` would fix the issue, it's a basic authorization coding failure of not observing the mantra *"protect from the server first, then from the client if necessary"*

Answer (score 2):

Meteor has a built in accounts functionality, so it has a login package called accounts-base that handles this for you.

The code is in the background and not in your main project files. You can view the package's contents here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-base.

Meteor is slightly different in the way security is handled. The tutorial you're using doesn't mention it much, perhaps this is why the question comes about.

Its slightly mentioned with the `insecure` package. In meteor you can't just update fields as you please in the database without corresponding `.allow` rules (docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#allow).

If you keep the insecure package in, installed by default, you can edit collections as you please. This is why the tutorial recommends removing it.

#### Allow rules and Publish

You can specify a rule that tells meteor that only certain users are allowed to alter the database.

Likewise when it comes to `autopublish`, you can control what database data is sent down from the server to the client.

Combined, these two are what make meteor secure in the same way as conventional web applications. You have a browser which can see html and js, but when it comes to what data it can see or what data it can update it is controlled in a secure fashion.

Comment: A useful and well written answer, but missing the point - question was about *authorization*, answer is about *authentication*. The tutorial actually results with unsafe code, I managed to insert a question without being logged in. Not sure if I should write how I did that... It's a security issue, but in a non-production mock app, I'm sure one of many with similar "vulnerabilities" deployed to meteor.com, dilemmas...

Comment: Isn't this what I address with the allow rules? You can't change fields unless you are authorized to do so. The tutorial mentions you should remove the `insecure` package, perhaps you did not do this & this is why you can insert questions in?

Comment: The author of the tutorial uses `Meteor.call` to change data in the collection and `allow` rules don't come into play (aren't used at all, I assume it means "deny all" since insecure package is removed). What happened is that author defined a well encapsulated API for data manipulation and protected clicks from the client side - so far so good - but then failed to protect that API from the server side which means you can do `Meteor.call` from the client and server will execute it even though the db update policy is "deny all" and client isn't logged in.

Comment: With Meteor.call you can still use something like `if(!Meteor.userId()) return` before anything else in the corresponding `.methods`. Sorry about that, I just skimmed through the tutorial but didn't see this. You can still control `.call`s permissions, though in a more custom way.

Comment: Yeah :) That's the point the tutorial author missed, with `Meteor.call` you **must** do something like `if(!Meteor.userId()) return`. I'm of the school that it's a good thing to have an abstraction layer between persistence and the view since it makes security concerns and separation of concerns between client and server more transparent, but I'm not sure if this is "the meteor way" to do things? Is there atm a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On client-side, you can use Meteor.userId() to manage display fo logged user or anonymous.
In fact you can think it's not secure, but in fact it's enough, if you think well your server-side code. Let's me explain :

In meteor Js, you manage collection through publish/subscribe and direct network call through Meteor.call. So you have to secure both, on server-side.

For the first one you have to remove insecure and autopublish.
Then use allow/deny on your collections to manage who can insert/update/remove data.
Then in your publish functions, that are only on server-side, you have to add :

```
if (!this.userId) return this.error(new Meteor.Error(403, 'unauthorized access'));
```

For the second one (Meteor.call) you just have to add in all required Meteor.methods (on server-side) :

```
if (!Meteor.userId()) throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'unauthorized access');
```

With those thing your application is "secure". Yes a user can hack your client code to try to display templates that should be available only for logged user, but in fact, this user will not be able to retreive any data, so yes it is secure !

Also don't forget to split your server and client code in different folder (server and client) or all the code will be downloaded by the client. And this is not secure !
Hope it helps you understand Meteor Js.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Rebolon, but you may have missed an important point here (or at least I misunderstand your answer). While adding a throw before `Meteor.call` "secures" the client-side, the thing you really want to secure is `Meteor.methods` on the server-side. Try protecting your code the way you described and then execute the appropriate `Meteor.call` through your browsers JS console and you'll see what I mean

Comment: You can try and fiddle with this through the tutorial linked in OP, autopublishing isn't an issue there and insecure package is removed, all db write access is done through `Meteor.call` and `Meteor.methods` and you can execute a `Meteor.call` from the JS console of the browser to add posts/upvote/downvote without logging in

Comment: All codes here are for server side, not client-side. So the Meteor.Error will be send by the server not by JS on client side.